# Consider $\Bbb{R}^n$ with the Euclidean metric. $\Bbb{R}^n \setminus {x_0}$ is an open set.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

> Consider $R^n$ with the Euclidean metric.
> For given $x_0$ $\in$ $R^n$, show that $R^n/{x_0}$ is an open set.

My proof:

If $x_0 ∈ B(a,r)$, put $δ= r−d(a,x_0) > 0$.
Let $y ∈ B(x_0, δ)$. Then
$d(y, a) ≤ d(y, x_0) + d(x_0, a)
< δ + d(a, x_0) = r$.

So $y ∈ B(a,r)$, and so
$B(x_0, δ) ⊂ B(a,r)$.

Any suggestion is very helpful, thank you very much.

Comment: For set removal use `\setminus`, not `/`. Also for the real numbers use `\Bbb{R}`.

Comment: To prove $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus x_0$ is open, you want to show for any $y \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus x_0$, we can find $\delta > 0$ so that $B(y,\delta) \subset \mathbb{R}^n \setminus x_0$. I'm quite sure what you did, but you can use $\delta = \frac{d(x_0,y)}{2}$.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to see your claim is to note that the real line is hausdorff and therefore $T_1$. Hence singletons are closed.

Here are two other ways of seeing singletons are closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$:

Note that if $(X,d)$ is a metric space, $F\subseteq X$ is closed if and only if $(x_n)_n\subseteq F$ such that $x_n\rightarrow x$, then $x\in F$. $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a metric space with the standard distance function.

In $\mathbb{R}^n$, if $(x_n)_n\subseteq \{x\}$ such that $x_n\rightarrow y$, then since $x_n=x$ for each $n$, it follows that $y=x$. Hence $\{x\}$ is closed.

Here is a direct way to show that complements of singletons in metric spaces are open:

Claim: If $(X,d)$ is a metric space and $x
\in X$ then $X\backslash \{x\}$ is open.

**Proof:** We shall use the definition of open sets. More concretely, we will show that if $y\in X\backslash \{x\}$ then there exists some $r>0$ such that the open ball centered at $y$, $B(y,r)$, is contained in $X\backslash \{x\}$.

As $y\neq x$, $d(y,x)>0$ . Thus we have a candidate for $r$: Put $r=d(y,x)$. We aim to show that $B(y,r) \subseteq X\backslash \{x\}$. To that end, observe that if $z\in B(y,r)$ then $d(z,y)< d(y,x)$. Thus if $z=x$ then $d(x,y)<d(x,y)$; so $z=x$ is absurd.

Please note that you do not need to be familiar with metric spaces. The proofs hold word for word when you consider $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the standard euclidean distance (which is an example of a metric space)